# Calendar icon missing in Access front end with SQL Server as back end

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, datetime

I have stored the dates in sql server in `datetime` format, but in the access front-end I am unable to see the calendar icon next to the date. It is because in `sql server the format is yyyy-mm-dd and in access it is mm/dd/yyyy` But Is there a way that I can get calendar icon in access front-end?